# Custom bootstrap popover in OpenLayers 5

Tags: javascript, openlayers, popup, css, bootstrap-framework

I try to set different custom for my bootstraps popovers : "popup" and "popup_ancien".

I can change CSS of my popovers together, by `.popover-content` or `.popover-title`, but how can I have two distinct custom?

My code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.2.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .mapy{
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
  <div id=coord>
      <input type="text" id="long" name="longitude">
      <input type="text" id="lati" name="latitude">
  </div>
    <div id="maps" class="maps"></div>
    <div id="popup_ancien"></div>
    <div style="display: none;">
      <!-- Popup -->
       <div id="popup" class="truc"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var mapy = new ol.Map({
          target: 'maps',
          layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile(
            {
                source: new ol.source.OSM({})
            })
          ],
          view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([9.13, 42.11]),
            zoom: 10
          })
        });

        var pos = ol.proj.fromLonLat([9.13, 42.11]);

        var popup_ancien = new ol.Overlay({
            element: document.getElementById('popup_ancien')
        });

        mapy.once('postrender', function(event) {
          popup_ancien.setPosition(pos);
          var element_ancien = popup_ancien.getElement();
          $(element_ancien).popover({
               placement: 'top',
               animation: false,
               html: true,
               content: '<p>Ancien emplacement</p>'
             });
          mapy.addOverlay(popup_ancien);
          $(element_ancien).popover('show');
        });

        var popup = new ol.Overlay({
            element: document.getElementById('popup'),

        });
        mapy.addOverlay(popup);

        document.getElementById("maps").style.cursor = "crosshair"; 

        mapy.on('click', event => {
          const coordWGS84 = ol.proj.transform([event.coordinate[0], event.coordinate[1]], 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
          document.getElementById("lati").value = coordWGS84[0];
          document.getElementById("long").value = coordWGS84[1];
          var element = popup.getElement();
          var coordinate = event.coordinate;
          $(element).popover('destroy');
          popup.setPosition(coordinate);
          console.log(element);
          $(element).popover({
            placement: 'top',
            animation: false,
            html: true,
            content: '<p>Votre nouvel emplacement</p>'
          });
          $(element).popover('show');
        });

    </script>
  </body>
  <style type="text/css">
        #marker {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #088;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #0FF;
        opacity: 0.5;
      }
      #vienna {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
      }
      #popup_ancien .popover-content {
        min-width: 200px;
        background: red;
      }
      .toto .popover-content {
        min-width: 200px;
        background: green;
      }
  </style>
</html>
```

**EDIT :**

One picture for explain what I'd like :

[image: explanation]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what actually you want to display? Maybe some screenshots or concept images. It's not clear at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually pure HTML, CSS & JS question, but sometimes one can forget about site rules if problem is interesting.

When Boostrap method `.popover` creates popover HTML element, id gives it unique `id`, but it does not expose it anywhere so it could be used to set CSS style class.  Workaround is to give `id` to popover HTML content. Then we can get parent of parent of this element which we are after. This looks something like this:

```
$(element_ancien).popover({
   placement: 'top',
   animation: false,
   html: true,
   content: '<p id="myPopup1">Ancien emplacement</p>'
});
$(element_ancien).popover('show');
var myPopover = $('#myPopup1').parent().parent();
```

Custom CSS style class can then be added to this element:

```
myPopover[0].classList.add('myClass1');
```

For CSS to be applied to the popup, it has to be declared the following way:

```
.myClass1 {
  background-color: lightgreen !important;
}
.myClass1 .arrow:after {
  border-top-color: lightgreen !important;
}
```

So to put it together:

```
<style>
...
  .myClass1 {
    background-color: lightgreen !important;
  }
  .myClass1 .arrow:after {
    border-top-color: lightgreen !important;
  }
...
</style>

<script>
...
  mapy.once('postrender', function(event) {
    popup_ancien.setPosition(pos);
    var element_ancien = popup_ancien.getElement();
    $(element_ancien).popover({
         placement: 'top',
         animation: false,
         html: true,
         content: '<p id="myPopup1">Ancien emplacement</p>'
       });
    mapy.addOverlay(popup_ancien);
    $(element_ancien).popover('show');
    var myPopover = $('#myPopup1').parent().parent();
    myPopover[0].classList.add('myClass1');
  });
...
</script>
```

Comment: It works perfectly ! Thank's ! I hesitated to publish it on stackoverflow, but because it's on mapping app I choose gis stackexchange.